# error: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, casting

I'm making a little app and I am getting the following error message:

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement

here is my code:

```
 try {
        //use com.mysql
        Statement statement=(Statement) koneksi.getConnection();
        String sql = "select * from agama";
        //use java.sql
        ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while(r.next()){
            Object[] o= new Object[2];
            o[0]=r.getString("id_agama");
            o[1]=r.getString("nama_agama");
            model.addRow(o);
        }
        r.close();
        statement.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

and my connection code:

```
 //use com.mysql
static Connection koneksi;
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    if(koneksi==null){
        //use com.mysql
        new Driver();
                             //use java.sql
        koneksi=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pendaftaran","root","");
    }
    return koneksi;
}
```

Comment: Please don't cast to driver-specific classes, restrict yourself to using the interfaces from package `java.sql`. It will make your code simpler, more portable, and less sensitive to implementation changes of drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`koneksi.getConnection()` returns a `Connection` , you can't cast it to a `Statement`, but you can get one by calling [createStatement()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement()) on the `Connection` .

```
Statement statement= koneksi.getConnection().createStatement();
```